# How can I write a decorator supporting the calling either with arguments or without arguments?

Tags: python

I'm learning the decorator in python.I want to write a decorator which can print"begin call" before i call the func and print"end call" after the calling.It's not difficult.
But now i want to improve this decorator.I want it not only support the usage like this:

```
@deco
def func():
    pass
```

but also support the usage like this:

```
@deco("execute")
def func()
    pass
```

And i have already written the codes:

```
def deco(text=None):
    if isinstance(text, str) or text == None:
        def _deco(func):
            def __deco(*args, **kw):
                print "%s call:" % text
                ret = func(*args, **kw)
                print "end call"
                return ret
            return __deco
        return _deco
    else:
        def _deco(*args, **kw):
            print "begin call:"
            ret = text(*args, **kw)
            print "end call:"
            return ret
        return _deco

@deco
def hello():
    print "hello"

@deco("execute")
def newhello():
    print "newhello"
```

and an IdentationError appears at line 17 "return ret".It says: unindent does not match any outer indentation level.
Can you tell me how to correct my code to meet my needs?

Comment: Correct your code indentation, please try with new code

Comment: Oh, sorry to bother you...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for decorators with arguments is a bit different - the decorator with arguments should return a function that will take a function and return another function. So it should really return a normal decorator. What I mean is, you can do something like this.

```
def decorator(argument):
    def real_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            funny_stuff()
            something_with_argument(argument)
            function(*args, **kwargs)
            more_funny_stuff()
        return wrapper
     return real_decorator
```

[Here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845) you can find more information about decorator.

Comment: Thank you.But if i write codes like these, how can i use the decorater like this:@decorator (without parentheses)?

Comment: you mean to say, your decorator should be having default arguments. So that you can use it either way. with arguments and without arguments. ???

Comment: Sorry, maybe my expression confused you...@decorator and @decorator() are not the same,if my decorator has default argument i can use it in this way @decorator(), but i also want to use it like this: @decorator, how can i write it?

Comment: Sorry to bother you...My code is correct, there are tabs mixed in with spaces.